# Headphone input missing 20.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, headset

**The problem:**

When I connect my headphone the mic doesn't get recognized. No input device is listed at all.

**Context:**

- Fresh install of ubuntu 20.04 on my desktop
- Codec: Realtek ALC887-VD
- Headset works on my dell laptop
- USB headset works just fine on my desktop
- Front panel detects as headphone (no input device is listed)
- Rear panel detecs as line-out

**Tried:**

- Using HDAjackretask to override front side green jack as Headphone (did nothing)
- Using HDAjackretask to override rear side green jack as Headphone (did nothing)
- Finding best option on https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/models.html (not found)
- Editing **alsa-base.conf** using:

  - options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi
  - options snd-hda-intel model=asrock-mobo
  - options snd-hda-intel model=headset-mic
  - options snd-hda-intel model=headset-mic

Answer (score 0):

First install `pavucontrol`:

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

Start it:

```
pavucontrol
```

Choose in `Configuration` the appropriate device and adjust the volume.

alternatively, you can also use

```
pacmd set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3 output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
```

You can find the exact name of your card (`here alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3`) by running:

```
pacmd list-cards
```